# How to add scrolling to form?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, forms, scroll

The user can upload images and then to view those images it opens them in a form. The problem is if the image is too big, then it cuts off the bottom. I want to be able to scroll in the form so I can see in the whole image. The form displays a print, download button etc. When I click the link to open the image, the form pops up. I can see the browser already has scrolls but I need the form that appears to have its own scroll.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id ="DivForm">
        <div id="tabsPOD" runat="server">                   
            <ul id="ulPODS" runat="server">

            </ul>                
        </div>

        <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormView">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <table class="buttons" style="top:42px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul style="margin-left:10px;">
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnPrint" runat="server" CssClass="btnPrint" OnClick="btnPrint_Click">Print</asp:LinkButton>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDownloadZip" runat="server" CssClass="btnDownload" OnClick="btnDownloadZip_Click">Download</asp:LinkButton>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDownloadImage" runat="server" CssClass="btnDownload" OnClick="btnDownloadImage_Click">Fullimage</asp:LinkButton>  
                                </li>
                                <li class="noPrint" style="float:right">
                                    <a title="Close" onclick="CloseForm()" class="btnCancelSmall">Close</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>                                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                             <asp:Image runat="server" ID="image" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                        
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected HtmlGenericControl GetDivPOD(int Count, JobDocket docket)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Image");
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Title");
        dt.Columns.Add("EITraxFlowName");
        dt.Columns.Add("EITraxImageID");
        DataRow desRow = dt.NewRow();
        desRow["Image"] = docket.PODImage;
        desRow["ID"] = docket.ID;
        desRow["Title"] = docket.DocketNo.Replace("|", ""); ;
        desRow["EITraxFlowName"] = docket.EiTraxFlowName;
        desRow["EITraxImageID"] = docket.EiTraxImageID;

        dt.Rows.Add(desRow);
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.ID = "pod-" + Count;
        FormView fv = new FormView();
        fv.ID = "FormViewPOD-" + Count;
        fv.ItemTemplate = FormView.ItemTemplate;
        fv.ItemCommand += new FormViewCommandEventHandler(fv_ItemCommand);
        fv.DataBound += (sender, e) => { fv_DataBound(sender, e, "POD"); };
        fv.DataSource = dt;
        fv.DataBind();
        div.Controls.Add(fv);
        return div;
    }
```

It then connects to the database to get the image name, id etc.

For the form:

```
void fv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e, string ImageType)
    {
        try
        {
            FormView FormView = sender as FormView;
            if (FormView != null)
            {
                DataRowView drv = FormView.DataItem as DataRowView;

                if (drv != null)
                {
                    image.ImageUrl = @"/thumbnail.ashx?ImgFilePath=" +    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PODFolder"] + "/" + Company.Current.CompCode + "/" + drv["Image"].ToString() + @"&width=" + ImageWidth.ToString() + "&height=" + ImageHeight.ToString();
                }
             }
         }
     }
```

How do I add a scroll to the form? I tried `style="overflow"` to the form and the div but it didn't work 
Here's a screen shot of what the pop up to display the image looks like:

[image]

Comment: have tried style="overflow:scroll"

Comment: @vbouk adding it to the line ` <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormView">` it doesn't display. But adding it to `<form id="form1" runat="server">` only shows it at the very top of the form not where the image is displayed. I've added an image to my question. The scroll only showed in the top bar

Answer (score 0):

in CSS add:

```
#FormView(or whatever the id of the form / element you want the scroll added to) {
overflow: auto; //this will add a scroll only if the page get's longer or 
                //wider than the client display. 
                //You can also force this behaviour if you want the scroll
                // to always be there by doing something like 
                //`overflow-x:scroll; or overflow-y:scroll;`
                //where x and y are the geometrical axis.(horizontal & vertical)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. No scroll bar is displaying

Comment: try adding an !important like so: `overflow: auto !important;` maybe there's another style that is preventing this. Also try and see if the specific styles are working (overflow-x and overflow-y, set them both to scroll. try with the !important here as well)

Comment: P.S., also set up a height and a width for that form, or set `width:auto;` and `max-height: 400px;` for instance, this should explicitly let the system know when to add the scroll bar.

Comment: Tried all that and the scroll bar still won't display. I couldn't find any other style that might be preventing the code.

Comment: have you checked in developer tools(press F12 in browser) if the right css files were loaded? If your working with multiple layout files it's easy to miss them :). try adding all this styles straight from there (the developer tools). The thing is, you only need a hight and a width in order for this to work.. unless that div has a fixed or absolute position, that might ruin it for you :).

Comment: what do you mean try adding all this styles straight from there (the developer tools)? How do I do that?

Comment: press F12 or right click on the page and go to inspect element, on the screen that pop's up you can see the source of the page and the css styles applied on each element. You can change those styles by simply clicking on them.

Comment: I don't think the css for FormView is working. I couldn't even find an id called FormView. I think something needs to be added to the  `void fv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e, string ImageType)` function

Comment: i'm sorry, the id for your form is form1 not formview, I mixed them up a bit, but you should already have known that :). form1 should work :). P.S., the `void fv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e, string ImageType)` is a backend method, it has nothing to do with your styles :)

Comment: ok finally got something. I put a div around the table cell that is displaying the image, the added your code to the css. The scroll bar is finally displaying but it's like the bottom of the scroll gets cut off. The image only scrolls down a small, not the full way down.

Comment: you have one of the containing divs set to fixed or absolute position. As I said before, that will prevent this from working, set that to relative and it should work.

Comment: Non of the other divs have style settings on them. Only thing that specifies width and height is the image `image.ImageUrl = @"/thumbnail.ashx?ImgFilePath=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PODFolder"] + "/" + Company.Current.CompCode + "/" + drv["Image"].ToString() + @"&width=" + ImageWidth.ToString() + "&height=" + ImageHeight.ToString();`

Comment: that has nothing to do with it, but you do need to specify width and height on the element where you want the scrollbar, so the form1 in your case.

Comment: ok I changed form1 to `<form id="form1" style="width:auto;max-height: 400px;" runat="server">` but it still cuts off the bottom. Tried putting the style onto the table. It changed the width but not the height. So I still couldn't scroll to the bottom